# Open large files?

Tags: files

I want to open just the head of a large file.

I know you can use a shell command (`M-! RET head file RET`), but I lose `helm` completion, it opens in a separate window, and the buffer has the uninformative name of `*Shell Command Output*`.

How can I open large files with `head` (or something similar)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I suggest you use the [`vlf` package](https://github.com/m00natic/vlfi).

It handles opening larges files in chunks and is very performant, I use it regularly to open files ~2gb.

In your config, require `vlf-setup` to have `vlf` ask you if you want to use `vlf` every time you try to open a large file. This means it works with anything that uses `find-file` such as `helm-find-files`.

Comment: Way better solution than what I was even asking for. Thanks a bunch!